# Android studio downloading button designs

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am trying to make a well designed app in Android-Studio, but I just can't get the buttons right. Where can I find good examples for button style?

Comment: https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons.html

Answer (score 0):

1st you can get buttons from the default system resources and also download or create your own button img file of at least 30x80

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would help but you can do it yourself:
In your "drawable folder" you can create a new "drawable resource file" and place this code there:

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<size android:height="50dp" android:width="50dp"></size>
<solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"></solid>
<corners android:radius="23dp"></corners>
```

In the xml file where you'll want to use it, add this piece of code to your "button tag" :

```
android:background="@drawable/round_button"
```